# Generating preview of posts on social media

Tags: php, facebook, google-plus, linkedin-api

This could be a fairly open question but I need to make posts to various social media websites such as facebook, twitter, linkedin, google etc. Now keep in mind that this is a true post and not just a share - in other words, I have stored the user credentials via OAuth and am going to make a formatted post to their wall, feed etc.

Question: Is there someway I can generate an exact or very close preview of the post on various social media? For example, can I show the user what their post will look like on facebook or google before they make the post?

I searched around the internet and all I could find is information about sharing.

I am using PHP, Javascript

Comment: That would be easiest, if you don’t make the post via API, but let the user make it themselves, via the respective Share buttons/dialogs these platforms offer …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the Open Graph tags of the URL with JavaScript or PHP, for example: https://github.com/fiann/jquery.ogp

You can put the tags together for a view, but you can never be 100% sure how it will look like, especially on Facebook.